# Is possible for javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane to take the remaining space in a Tab panel?

Tags: javafx

I have a fxml file containing a ScrollPanel, that I use to display an image, inside a TabPanel:

```
<Tab text="Example" fx:id="liveTab" fx:controller="me.example.ExampleController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <content>
    <HBox prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1200.0">
      <children>
        <FlowPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="400.0">
          <children>
            <ScrollPane  prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <content>          
                <ListView fx:id="listView" prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="190.0">
                  <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    </FXCollections>
                  </items>
                </ListView>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>   
            <ScrollPane  prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <content>
                <ListView prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="190.0">
                  <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    </FXCollections>
                  </items>
                </ListView>
              </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="400.0" spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
              <Button  text="Add"/>
              <Button  text="Remove"/>
            </HBox>
          </children>
        </FlowPane>
        <VBox>
          <children>
            <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true">
              <content>
               <ImageView fx:id="imageContainer" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Koala.jpg" preserveRatio="true" />
                </ImageView>     
             </content>
            </ScrollPane>
          </children>
        </VBox>
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </content>
</Tab>
```

I want the ImageView to take all the remaining space of the containing tab, I have tried to use fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true", and change from a FlowPane to a VBox but I keep getting this:

[image: TabPanel layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to get the desired behavior. Using AnchorPane one can force the children nodes to take the space relative to the parent. I share the code just in case someone finds it useful:

```
<Tab text="Example" fx:id="liveTab" fx:controller="me.example.ExampleController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <content>
    <AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1200.0">
      <children>
        <FlowPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="400.0">
          <children>
            <ScrollPane  prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <content>          
                <ListView fx:id="listView" prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="190.0">
                  <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    </FXCollections>
                  </items>
                </ListView>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>   
            <ScrollPane  prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <content>
                <ListView prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="190.0">
                  <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    </FXCollections>
                  </items>
                </ListView>
              </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="400.0" spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
              <Button  text="Add"/>
              <Button  text="Remove"/>
            </HBox>
          </children>
        </FlowPane>
        <AnchorPane AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="400.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <ScrollPane AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                <content>
                    <ImageView fx:id="imageContainer" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Koala.jpg" preserveRatio="true" />
                    </ImageView>     
                </content>
            </ScrollPane>
        </AnchorPane>
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </content>
</Tab>
```

and the result:

[image: Desired Behavior]

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
<ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true">
...
```

help?

Comment: it didn't, the parent container is 1200px long, and my scroll panel has a sibling 400px long, I want it to take the 800px left but it does not, it is taking the remaining height though.

Comment: @Amaury. Then you are using wrong layout panel. Try VBox instead of FlowPane.

Comment: although it helped using a HBox (I want the remaining space horizontally) I am still getting the same problem, the scrollPane is only 100px wide if I do not specify prefWidth="400.0"

Comment: I updated the question, sorry for the wait, I had to keep moving with the other functionality.